# How to not repeat yourself with SQL where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2016

I have a stored procedure which includes this:

```
declare @dueTypeCode nvarchar(3) = 'ALL' --Is actually a parameter that is passed into the stored procedure
declare @today DateTime = GetUtcDate();
declare @tomorrow DateTime = dateadd(day,datediff(day,-1,GETUTCDATE()),0);
declare @fiveDaysFromNow DateTime = dateadd(day,datediff(day,-5,GETUTCDATE()),0);

if(@dueTypeCode = 'ALL')

    Select * from Items

ELSE IF (@dueTypeCode = 'TODAY')

    Select * from Items where DueDate =  @today

ELSE IF (@dueTypeCode = 'NEXT5DAYS')    

    Select *  from Items where  DueDate  >= @today and DueDate <= @fiveDaysFromNow 
END
```

Is there any way to wrap this into a single SQL statement to avoid repetition of  the above code?

The actual select statement is much more complicated, and repeating it 3 times just to vary the where clause seems a violation of the DRY principle.

Comment: Have you considered using Dynamic SQL or putting all the logic in a single `WHERE` and include the `RECOMPILE` option?

Comment: yes and no.  You can use boolean logic to control which part of the logic wins according to what @dueTypeCode is set to, but then you are taking the risk of creating an inefficient query.  The greater complexity of the logic may confound the query optimiser.  So watch out for 'catch all' queries becoming inefficient.

Comment: @Larnu, No, I had not considered Dynamic Sql.  Yes, I have considered the single where clause, but not sure how to do that.

Comment: Peruse this [dynamic search conditions article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

Comment: @DanGuzman, that is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
select i.*
from Items i
where (@dueTypeCode = 'ALL') or
      (@dueTypeCode = 'TODAY' and DueDate = @today) or
      (@dueTypeCode = 'NEXT5DAYS' and DueDate >= @today and DueDate <= @fiveDaysFromNow);
```

The downside is that this is likely not to be as efficient as the original queries -- if indexes can be used for that query (particularly on `DueDate`).

Comment: I don't get why something like this would not be able to use an index (ie be more inefficient.) Would adding the `RECOMPILE` option be the answer to that?

Comment: Adding an `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` hint may provide a better plan but at the cost of query compilation, which not be a concern if the query isn't frequently executed.

Comment: build the query, then look at the query execution plan and/or do some tests.

Comment: @GregGum . . . This has to do with parameter sniffing and the fact that SQL Server chooses the execution plan based on the first execution of the query.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using variables why don't you just modify the variables:

```
DECLARE @dueTypeCode NVARCHAR(10) = 'NEXT5DAYS';
DECLARE @date1 DATE = NULL;
DECLARE @date2 DATE = NULL;

IF @dueTypeCode = 'TODAY'
BEGIN
    SET @date1 = GETUTCDATE();
    SET @date2 = GETUTCDATE() + 1;
END
ELSE IF @dueTypeCode = 'NEXT5DAYS'
BEGIN
    SET @date1 = GETUTCDATE();
    SET @date2 = GETUTCDATE() + 6;
END

SELECT * FROM Items
WHERE (@date1 IS NULL OR DueDate >= @date1)
AND   (@date2 IS NULL OR DueDate <  @date2)
```

Answer (score 1):

My style :

```
   declare @dueTypeCode nvarchar(3) = 'ALL' --Is actually a parameter that is passed 
   into the stored procedure
   declare @today DateTime = GetUtcDate();
   declare @tomorrow DateTime = dateadd(day,datediff(day,-1,GETUTCDATE()),0);
   declare @fiveDaysFromNow DateTime = dateadd(day,datediff(day,-5,GETUTCDATE()),0);

   Select * 
   from Items
   where 1= case @dueTypeCode 
        when 'ALL' then 1
        when 'TODAY' then
            case when DueDate =  @today then 1 else 0 end
        when 'NEXT5DAYS' then
            case when DueDate  >= @today and DueDate <= @fiveDaysFromNow  then 1 else 0 end
        else
            0
        end
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off what Gordon posted - you could get optimal performance with Dynamic SQL. Starting with this sample data:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
USE tempdb;
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.items','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.items;
GO

SELECT col1    = CAST(NEWID() AS VARCHAR(100)), 
       DueDate = ISNULL(DATEADD(DAY,t.c*2,d.dt),d.dt)
INTO   dbo.items
FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(1),(2),(3),(4)) AS t(c)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))) AS d(dt);
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cl_nu__dbo_items__DueDate ON dbo.items(DueDate);
GO
```

**Solution:**

```
DECLARE @dueTypeCode VARCHAR(100) = 'TODAY' --'NEXT5DAYS --'ALL';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000) = 
N'SELECT i.*
FROM dbo.Items i'+CHAR(10);

SELECT @sql += 
  CASE @dueTypeCode 
    WHEN 'TODAY'     THEN 'WHERE DueDate = CAST(getdate() AS date);'
    WHEN 'NEXT5DAYS' THEN 'WHERE DueDate >= CAST(getdate() AS date) AND DueDate <= DATEADD(DAY,5,CAST(getdate() AS date))'
    ELSE ''
  END;

EXEC sp_executesql @statement = @sql;
```

Obviously the business logic would need to be updated to match your needs (e.g. Note my lazy use of `ELSE ''` which handles "ALL" as well as anything else, this will need to be changed). That said, here's the execution plan when choosing "TODAY" or "NEXT5DAYS". An index seek in this situation is basically the best you can hope for.

[image]